# How make a loading animation while ajax is loading?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can i show a loading animation while ajax is loading?
so far i could make an animation using react loaidng webpack
aind now i want it to show when ajax is loading is it possible??

```html
class PersonList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    persons: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      .then(res => {
        const persons = res.data;
        this.setState({ persons });
      })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <tbody style={{"background":"#c3e6cb"}}>
        {
          this.state.persons
            .map(person =>
        <tr key={person.id}>
          <td>{person.name}</td>
          </tr>
            )
        }
        </tbody>
    )
  }
}

function Preloader(){


    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [done, setDone] = useState(undefined);

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                setData(json);
                setDone(true);  
            });
        }, 1000);
    })
```

Comment: You could add an 'isLoading' property to your state. Every time when you call your API, you just do setIsLoading(true), and in your .then() or .catch() do setIsLoading(false).
In your UI, you can then just look to the isLoading state and show your loader accordingly.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, ***[search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=react+ajax+animation+site%3Astackoverflow.com)***

Answer (score 1):

First set in your state when its loading

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({isLoading: true});
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      .then(res => {
         const persons = res.data;
         this.setState({ persons });
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({isLoading: true});
      })
  }
```

Then in your render function take that into consideration

```
render() {
    return (
        <>
            {this.state.isLoading
              ? <div>**Some loading animation**</div>
              : <tbody style={{"background":"#c3e6cb"}}>
                {
                  this.state.persons
                    .map(person =>
                <tr key={person.id}>
                  <td>{person.name}</td>
                  </tr>
                    )
                }
                </tbody>
           }
         </>
    )
  }
```

Comment: where should i close </>?

Comment: My bad, fixed the answer

Comment: i got syntax error for <></> i have used it in another place  Now What should i do now??